# How do you select extreme details for all units and buildings in Rise of Nations?

Tags: rise-of-nations

You can usually select an option that will allow you to see special info about buildings and units such as health and what is attacking it. How do I toggle that on and off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I finally found it. Go under Options/Tools in the main menu. From there under game, click on show advanced details button.